# Call Instagram API from localhost

Tags: php, api, instagram

Is it possible to get **INSTAGRAM** user details through API from **localhost** ?

Because I am trying to doing this from localhost but unable to fetch the information.
After click the login url it redirect me to the **INSTAGRAM** and after successfully login and authorize the apps it redirect me properly in my callback URL with code. But when I am trying to fetch the info (cURL) using access token then it return null.

But same code run perfectly in live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I resolved the problem. now I am able to connect to *Instagram*.

I use the [*CodeIgniter Instagram Library by Ian Luckraft*](http://ianluckraft.co.uk).
In config file I just change the

```
$config['instagram_ssl_verify'] = FALSE;
```

By default it was `TRUE`.

Comment: you can check a simillar video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWithhiVFOU)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the [Curl option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to false. Find the Curl request in your code and add or edit an option that will look something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  <<-- Add this line
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.
You can try using Instagram api wrapper which is made by Galen Grover 
https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API
Mine's works just fine

Comment: sorry to inform you that I am already used that code and unable to fetch information from localhost.

Answer (score -1):

```
in instagram .config.php in your localhost 
you must  set 'apiCallback' =>

to  'http://localhost/instagram/instagram/'


folder of your success.php


<?php
// Setup class
  $instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey'      => '',
    'apiSecret'   => '',
    'a
?>piCallback' => 'http://localhost/instagram/instagram/' // must point to success.php
  ));
```